# Eclipse context menu items removal

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've searched on the internet about removing some of the right click context menu items such as Copy, Run as...,Show in and others and I didn't saw a certain answer about this.

Is it possible to remove these contextual menus without actually removing the plugins that add these contributions to it , a kind of filter for the contextual menu ?

Comment: Possibly you could use [activities](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm) to suppress some menu items, but I am not sure if this works for context menus, and it takes a lot of research to work out the required patterns.

Comment: I think of removing contextual menus while in application without the need to restart Eclipse like Customize Perspective works. Is the contextual menu created dinamically on right-click ?

Comment: There are several ways to create a context menu, some are static, some dynamic. The only way to tell for a particular menu is to find how it is created in the source.